# mongodb: remove documents in a collection that ref non-existing document in a different collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have zombie documents in `collection1` that reference documents which have been deleted from `collection2`

```
const collection1 = new Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  ref: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'collection2' }

})
```

how can I loop through all docs in `collection1` and remove any doc that `refs` a non-existing ObjectId in `collection2`?

Comment: You can try using the aggregation `$lookup`  to identify the not-matching documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An aggregation solution would be ideal but the following worked for my use case:

```
const removeZombies = async () => {
  const col1 = await collection1.find({})
  col1.forEach(async item => {
    const colRef = await collection2.findById(item.ref)
    if (colRef === null) {
      collection1.deleteOne({ _id: item._id })
        .then(doc => console.log(doc))
    }
  })
}
```